# German character encoding in Linux system using java

Tags: java, linux, encoding

I have a `.CSV` file which contains **German** characters such as `ö`

My code to read that file as a Reader is given below:

```
InputStreamReader inputFileReader = new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(inputile));
```

This works fine in Windows system and character is coming as `ö` itself. But my application is deployed in `Linux` system. In `Linux`, the specific character is skipped. Verification was done in MySQL DB.

How we can handle this case in a `Linux` system?

Comment: How exactly do you check that the character is coming as question mark? Do you try to print it in a terminal or do you check it's numeric value?

Comment: can you try this: new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Comment: When UTF-8 is used, character is not shown in MySQL DB.
The default character set shown in Linux environment as UTF-8

Comment: You may need to set mysql column collation to utf8_bin

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of different character encodings.

Comment: Nimesh, but when we directly saves this ö to DB, it is showing correctly. When saving through code it is not coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux there are two charsets which are mainly used for German and many other Western European languages: UTF-8 and Latin-1, known as ISO-8859-1 as well. You should first determine which charset your cvs file is using. You can use the command `file`(1), e. g. `file -I file.csv`. Then, you can use Nimesh's suggestion: `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`.

Comment: Thanks macmoonshine, new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1) is worked.

Just for clarification, Is there any chance this charset would be changed in future? Like change in file

Comment: This charset is defined by iso.org. I don't believe they will change this norm. ;) They provider of your cvs file may change the charset in future, but he must have any good reason for this. There some libraries for automatic charset detection (e. g. ICU CharsetDetector http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html).